# How to restrict insert in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, insert

If a user got allow to insert data, they may insert anythings in a object. How to restrict user insert without Method?

(I don't want user some additional library if it's not a silver bullet.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use another library: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2 . It's widely used in meteor community.

It permits to validate collection against a schema.

Comment: OK, i see telescope use it, Thx.

Comment: As a general rules you should check answer if you think that satisfy your question.

Comment: Here's a [post](http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/07/meteor-security-no-2-all-praise-aldeed.html) on usage of collection2 to improve collection security.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is pretty straight forward. Deny insertion from client side and create server side method using `Meteor.methods`  for inserting data. Then just call the server method in client using `Meteor.apply`

check out denying rules [`here`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deny)

Comment: It's a options, but i want know what time to using direct insert .

Comment: It depends on your use case. mostly database related tasks are done in server side for security purpose. but you can allow client side insertion if the requirement permits so.